# Cmake error at CmakeLists.txt:3 (include)

Tags: r, ubuntu, cmake, xgboost

I am trying to build the R package with GPU support to run xgboost following these steps, in ubuntu 20.04:

1. XGboost was installed from Rstudio with install.packages("xgboost")
2. cmake is installed from terminal with the command: sudo snap install cmake `--classic`
3. CMake version 3.21.2 was installed and verified
4. The terminal command:cmake .. `-DUSE_CUDA=ON -DR_LIB=ON` is used from the `~xgboost/build/`
   directory following the procedure from [here](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#building-r-package-with-gpu-support), but it shows several errors related to the CMakeLists.txt file as shown below ...I downloaded the CMakeLists.txt file from [GitHub](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost), and placed it in the `~/xgboost/` path, but errors keep showing

How may I correct those errors? Thank you in advance for any advice!

[This is my ubuntu 20.04 terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/us8fE.png)

------- ubuntu 20.04 terminal ---

```
ricardo@ricardo:~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/xgboost/build$ 


cmake .. -DUSE_CUDA=ON -DR_LIB=ON


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    cmake/Utils.cmake


-- CMake version 3.21.2
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:20 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    /home/ricardo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/xgboost/cmake/FindPrefetchIntrinsics.cmake


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:21 (find_prefetch_intrinsics):
  Unknown CMake command "find_prefetch_intrinsics".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

See also "/home/ricardo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/xgboost/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Comment: Obviously a single `CMakeLists.txt` is not sufficient for build the whole project: You need to download the entire repository.

Comment: Thanks, Tsyvarev , I downloaded it all and copied only the required CMakeLists.txt to the xgboost installed version. ¿ Do you suggest to re install xgboost from github ?

Comment: [The link](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#building-r-package-with-gpu-support) you use describes how to build xgboost. For that you need to have all its sources, not just `CMakeLists.txt`. Even the description tells "On Linux, starting from the **XGBoost directory**".